# Fourth solution of $y'=\dfrac {10}{3} x y^{2/5}$, $y(0)=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

By inspection, we know that 
$y=0$ is a solution. If we separate variables, we get another solution, $y=x^{10/3}$. The book tells me this much, and asks me to find the other  $2$ solutions that differ on every open interval containing $x=0$ and are defined on $(-\infty, \infty)$

I found the third solution (by guessing) to be $y=-x^{10/3}$. The only other possibility i could think about is $x=0$, but I'm pretty sure that's not valid since $y'$ would be undefined. What is the last solution? How do we know there are only $4$ possible solutions (and not more)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y = -x^{10/3}$ is not a solution.  It is decreasing where it should be increasing and increasing where it should be decreasing.

You could have any one of $y = 0$ and $y =  x^{10/3}$ 
for $x \ge 0$, and any one of those for $x < 0$.  That makes $4$ different solutions.

There are also solutions of the form
$$ y = \cases{(x^2 - a^2)^{5/3}  & for $x < a$\cr
              0 & for $a \le x \le b$\cr
             (x^2 - b^2)^{5/3} & for $x > b$\cr}$$
where $-\infty \le a < 0 < b \le +\infty$, but these don't differ on every open interval containing $0$.

Comment: Why isn't $y=-x^{10/3}$ a solution? Can't we write $y'=-\dfrac {10}{3} x^{7/3} = \dfrac {10}{3} x \cdot (-x^{4}{3} )= \dfrac {10}{3} x (-x^{10}{3})^{2/5}= \dfrac {10}{3} x y^{2}{5}$? Also, how can $y=0$ for $x<0$ be a solution to the initial condition $y(0)=0$ if it doesn't contain $x=0?$? And sorry i forgot to mention, but the book says there are 4 solutions defined on $(-\infty, \infty)$ which differ on every open interval containing x= 0

Comment: Check the signs.  If $x > 0$, $-\dfrac{10}{3} x^{7/3} < 0$ while $\dfrac{10}{3} x y^{2/5} > 0$.

Comment: I didn't say $y = 0$ for $x < 0$ is a solution.  The four solutions are:
$$y = 0 $$
$$ y = x^{10/3} $$
$$ y = \cases{0 & for $x \le 0$\cr
                       x^{10/3} & for $x > 0$\cr}$$
$$ y = \cases{x^{10/3} & for $x \le 0$\cr
                      0 & for $x > 0$\cr}$$